# My localNotification isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

i got following code which contains my localNotification:

```
-(void)scheduleNotification{

    if (self.shouldRemind && [self.dueDate compare:[NSDate date]] != NSOrderedAscending){

        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
        localNotification.fireDate = self.dueDate;
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertBody = self.text;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.itemId] forKey:@"ItemId"];

        NSLog(@"Scheduled notification %@ for itemId %d", localNotification, self.itemId);

    }
}
```

My output in NSLog says following:

2013-07-28 15:39:48.684 JuneChecklist[2271:907] Scheduled notification {fire date = воскресенье, 28 июля 2013 г., 15:40:33 Московское стандартное время, time zone = Europe/Moscow (GMT+04:00) offset 14400, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = воскресенье, 28 июля 2013 г., 15:40:33 Московское стандартное время, user info = {
    ItemId = 0;
}} for itemId 0

But it is not shown (i tried launch app on iPhone and Simulator). I wonder why it shown fireDate in NSLog perfectly, but there is no notification when i wait for that time.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But where is [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];?

Comment: Thank you now its work. That chunk of code come from tutorial, i wonder why author forget such simple thing.